# is there any way to add an image in the following code?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a simple website using django and following bootstrap5 examples.
I'd like to know if there is any way to add a image
in the indicated spot from the following picture.

[image]

here is the code:

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}
{% block header %}
<main class="container">
  <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
      <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic">Title of a longer featured blog post</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers 
quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
      <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white fw-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
{% endblock header %}
{% block content %}
  <p> this is a content block </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code:

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}
{% block header %}
<main class="container">
  <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
      <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic">Title of a longer featured blog post</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers 
quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
      <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white fw-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
            <img  src="" alt="" />
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</main>
{% endblock header %}
{% block content %}
  <p> this is a content block </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: the image seems to go under the texts. how could I possibly set it next to the texts but not under?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).